# WCF and Fluent NHibernate: how can i keep "clean" classes?

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

i'm investigating Nhibernate, jquery and WCF at the same time for a in-house project, and i was wondering why i couldn't have "clean" data classes.

From what i've read, a very good point in the nhibernate world is that my business class won't be linked to the framework.
I won't have

```
<SaveInTable("Thingie")> _
Public Class Thingie
    <ColumnName("ThingieId")> _
    Public Property Id as Integer
    ' accessors
End Class
```

but rather something like

```
Public Class Thingie
Public Property Id as Integer
' etc
```

And then

```
Public Class ThingieMapping
Inherits ClassMap(Of Thingie)
' etc, omitted for brevity's sake
```

What i don't understand is that if i want to list *Thingie*s in a web page with *jQuery*, and if i want to use WCF webservices with jquery (it looks like the current trend from what i've seen on various tutorials), i find myself having to add *DataContract* and *DataMember* attributes to my *Thingie* class.
On the other hand, the classic ASMX webservices won't bother me and let me retrieve the *Thingie* class without worrying about adding attributes.

I have the feeling that i'm missing part of the picture here; it seems logical to try keeping the *Thingie* class mostly independent, but i haven't found examples so far.

So, do i have to abandon all hopes and stick to the classic webservices, or is there a way to have my WCF cake and eat it too?

Comment: As a matter of fact, i spoke a bit early yesterday when i said that the classic webservices were working. I just hadn't implemented methods with IList and the generic collections.
As it happens, if i wanted to use webservices, i would have to exclude the collections from the serialization, which again kind of defeats the idea of a clean class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use DTOs to send over the wire - then you can decorate the DTOs with the necessary attributes.

This means, of course, that you must somehow map your domain classes to the DTOs and vice versa. If the mapping is trivial (+some other cases that satisfies some conventions), you can use [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) for that.

Using DTOs has several benefits, the best being that you have a clear seperation of concerns - your NHibernate-mapped domain model is about modeling stuff in your domain, and your DTOs are for sending data over the wire. Then, if one changes, the other doesn't necessarily need to change as well.